# Comparing Arrays of Arrays

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, f#, simd

So I have two arrays, a and b of varying size containing child arrays of the same length and both are of the same type as are the child arrays (float for example).

I want find all the matches for the child arrays in b within the child arrays of array a.

Now I'm looking for a faster or better way to do this (perhaps CUDA or SIMD coding).

At the moment I have something like (F#):

```
let mutable result = 0.0
for a in arrayA do:
 for b in arrayB do:
  if a = b then 
   result <- result + (a |> Array.sum)
```

My array a contains around 5 Million elements and array b contains around 3000. Hence my performance related issue.

Comment: what are "child" arrays? how big are those arrays? please post a minimal demo data set and your desired output.

Comment: in addition to that, how do you define "equality" for floating point values? do you take into account some `epsilon`?

Comment: It might be worth sorting one or both arrays first, so you can do this in O(NlogN + MlogM) time instead of O(N*M).  If you eliminate and count duplicates while sorting, you don't have to do it while looping.  Actually, just sort the shorter array, then for each `a`, binary-search for it in `arrayB`.  Sorting is esp. valuable if you are going to do slower comparisons with a tolerance.

Comment: I have specified estimated sizes in the last paragraph. I think to avoid precision issues, I will use decimal, and more so as it's currency related information I'm looking to process.

Comment: Thanks for your comments they both helped me tune the looping somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use bruteforce algorithm to solve the problem. Suppose that *A* and *B* have sizes *N* and *M* respecively, each small array you are checking for equality is *K* elements long. Your algorithm takes *O(N M K)* time in worst case and *O(N M + Z K)* in best case, given that number of matches is *Z* (which may attain *N M*).

Notice that each of your small arrays is essentially a string. You have two sets of strings, and you want to detect all equal pairs between them.

This problem can be solved with [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Create a hash table with *O(M)* cells. In this table, store strings of array *B* without duplication. After you have added all the strings from *B*, iterate over strings from *A* and check if they are present in the hash table. This solution can be implemented as randomized one with *O((M + N) K)* time complexity on average, which is linear of the input data size.

Also, you can solve the problem in non-randomized way. Put all the strings into a single array *X* and sort them. During sorting, put strings from *A* after all equal strings from *B*. Note that you should remember which strings of *X* came from which array. You can either use some fast [comparison sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), or use [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). In the latter case sorting is done in linear time, i.e. in *O((M + N) K)*.

Now all the common strings are stored in *X* contiguously. You can iterate over *X*, maintaining the set of strings from *B* equal to the currently processed string. If you see a string different from the previous one, clear the set. If the string is from *B*, add it to the set. If it is from *A*, record that it is equal to the set of elements from *B*. This is a single pass over *X* with *O(K)* time per string, so it takes *O((M + N) K)* time in total.

If length *K* of your strings is not tiny, you can add vectorization to string operations. In case of hash table approach, most time would be spent on computing string hash. If you choose [polynomial hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing#Hashing_strings) modulo 2^32, then it is easy to vectorize it with SSE2. Also, you need fast string comparison, which can be done with `memcmp` function, which can be easily vectorized too. For the sorting solution, you need only string comparisons. Also, you might want to implement a radix sort, which is not possible to vectorize, I'm afraid.

Efficient parallelization of both approaches is not very simple. For the first algorithm, you need a concurrent hash table. Actually, there are even some [lock-free hash tables](http://preshing.com/20130605/the-worlds-simplest-lock-free-hash-table/) out there. For the second approach, you can  parallelize the first step (quicksort is easy to parallelize, radix sort is not). The second step can be parallelized too if there are not too many equal strings: you can split the array *X* into almost equal pieces, breaking it only between two different strings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very insightful, I had thought about hashing which I'll implement and see.

Answer (score 2):

You may save some time comparing large arrays by splitting them into smaller arrays and doing the equality check in parallel.

This chunk function is taken directly from [F# Snippets](http://www.fssnip.net/k2)

```
let chunk chunkSize (arr : _ array) = 
query {
  for idx in 0..(arr.Length - 1) do
  groupBy (idx / chunkSize) into g
  select (g |> Seq.map (fun idx -> arr.[idx]))
}
```

Then going something like this to compare arrays. I have chosen to split each array into 4 smaller chunks:

```
let fastArrayCompare a1 a2 = async {
let! a =
  Seq.zip (chunk 4 a1) (chunk 4 a2)
  |> Seq.map (fun (a1',a2') -> async {return a1' = a2'}) 
  |> Async.Parallel
return Array.TrueForAll (a,(fun t -> t))}
```

Obviously you now adding some extra time with the array splitting but with lots of very large array comparisons you should make up this time and then some.

Comment: I had used the F# ChunkBySize to make the child arrays of equal lengths already. Its present in F# 4.0.0.1 core, Cheers.